# ¿Convertir texto con valor numérico a número usando as.numeric()?

Tags: r, caracteres, números-enteros

Tengo un df en CSV. Al importarlo a R, me importa una variable numérica como carácter. He intentado convertirla con as.numeric lo cual da error

El código es el siguiente:

```
survival <- read.csv("survival.amp.csv", header = T, dec = ",", sep = ";")
```

La estrcutura de la variable en r:

str(survival$sd.percentage)

chr [1:57] "1,89" "1,89" "1,89" "0,24"

Intentando cambiar de carácter a numero:

```
survival$sd.percentage <- as.numeric(survival$sd.percentage)
```

Warning message:
NAs introducidos por coerción

Comment: Los número que diste de ejemplo, parecen que tiene una coma como separador decimal, pero eso no debe ser el problema por que lo estás contemplando con `dec = ","` .  Hay algún otro valor que no permite tratar la columna como numérica, podrías obtener estos valores así: `survival$sd.percentage[is.na(as.numeric(gsub(",", ".",survival$sd.percentage)))]`

Comment: Bienvenida user a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, el problema es el formato de tus números. A simple vista parece ser que son números decimales con coma, cuando deberían ser decimales con punto, esto para que `as.numeric` no te de ese error.

Una solución podría ser hacer el reemplazo de esa coma (`,`) por un punto (`.`) antes de hacer la conversión.

```
survival$sd.percentage <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", survival$sd.percentage))
```